# How do I implement a random number for my guessing game that doesn't keep changing until the user guesses it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Every time I click "Confirm," it generates a new random number, so you can't actually guess it. And how do I display the number of tries the user has attempted guessing the number? Please help as I have been stuck on this for hours. Thanks!

```
const Home = () => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");
  const [confirmed, setConfirmed] = useState(false);
  const [selectedNumber, setSelectedNumber] = useState();

  const input = inputText => {
    setEnteredValue(inputText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setEnteredValue("");
    setConfirmed(false);
  };

  const confirm = () => {
    const chosenNum = parseInt(enteredValue);
    setConfirmed(true);
    setSelectedNumber(chosenNum);
    setEnteredValue("");
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let count = 0;
    if (!enteredValue) {
      Alert.alert("Please Enter a Number");
    } else if (chosenNum > x) {
      Alert.alert("Guess Lower");
      count+=1
    } else if (chosenNum < x) {
      Alert.alert("Guess Higher");
      count+=1
    } else if (chosenNum == x) {
      Alert.alert("You Guessed Correctly");
    }
  };

  let confirmedOutput;
  if (confirmed) {
    confirmedOutput = (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.output}>Chosen Number: {selectedNumber}</Text>
        <Text>Tries: </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Math.random() vanillaJavaScript method

Comment: Hello, you want to 1) show the number of wrong attempts users had?  2) Keep the guess number fix until the user correctly guesses it?

Comment: @NehaSharma Yes please

Answer (score 0):

You're generating the x number inside the `confirm` function. So each time user guess (correct or not) x will be changed.

You should bring this:

```
let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
let count = 0;
```

out the function, somewhere when the game start, it'll be called.

And re-gen new x and reset count, when user guesses correct:

```
// ...
 } else if (chosenNum == x) {
      Alert.alert("You Guessed Correctly");
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      count = 0;
 }
```

`count` is the user tries atempt, show it in view.

Comment: How would I be able to display the number of counts? And where should I put the x and count = 0 before the game starts?

Comment: I don't know how you structure your components so dont know  exactly where the game start. Put it right first in that `Home` component, under `useState` lines, you can display `count` the  same way as `selectedNumber`: `<Text>Tries: {count}</Text>`

Comment: What do you mean the same as selectedNumber? How would count and x be used if they are outside of the function?

Comment: `<Text>Tries: {count}</Text>`? So put them in `Home` scope, not `confirm` function scope